# single quote on float values (spatie: Simple excel laravel)

Tags: spout

When trying to fetch records from the Database (MySQL) to the excel-sheet using the spatie library in laravel, the sheet comes with a single quote attached to the numerical values.
How can this be solved?
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7h7v.jpg)

I have converted the fetched numerical values to float in a function, but then if a value = 2.40, it will display 2.4 even after using the round() and number_format() in  php, yet i want 2.40 in number format and not string format.